# var inside function gets undefined (JavaScript, NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having problem with the call of some function, I'm learning JavaScript and NodeJS with the knowledge I get from JavaScript, I don't see the clue why I have this error, the function I'm trying to do is this one:

```
function isFileView(dat)
{
    var file = dat;

    //Check if im gettint the right data.
    console.log('file is ' + dat);
    var extension = file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;

    if(extension != 0)
    {
        switch (extension)
        {
            case 'html':
                return file;
                break;

            case 'css':
                return file;
                break;

            case 'js':
                return file;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        file = file + '.html';
        return file;
    }
}
```

The `dat` value returns as `undefined` and is making my server to stop. I've changed the parameter of the function and the variables inside the function but no clue. This is the whole script I've made so far:

```
//Load modules
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

//Send message to console.
console.log('starting.');

//Load config JSON file and 
var content = fs.readFileSync("config.json");
var config = JSON.parse(content);
var server_ip = config.server_ip;
var port = config.port;

console.log('Started.');

//Create server.
server = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    //if url has GET method.
    if(request.url.lastIndexOf('?') != -1)
    {
        //resolve url only view.
        var view = getUrlView(request.url);

        console.log('requested: ' + view);
        console.log(methodGet(request.url));

        //Get requested page
        fs.readFile('./views' + view + '.html', function(error, data)
        {

            //if error returned, send error message
            if(error)
            {
                response.writeHead(400, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
                response.end('Page was not found');
            }

            //if error was not returned, send the html
            else
            {
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
                response.end(data);
            }
        });

        if(view == '/')
        {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end('Hello world from node.js');
        }
    }

    else
    {
        console.log('requested: ' + request.url);
        isFileView(view);

        //Get requested page
        fs.readFile('./views' + request.url + '.html', function(error, data)
        {

            //if error returned, send error message
            if(error)
            {
                response.writeHead(400, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
                response.end('Page was not found');
            }

            //if error was not returned, send the html
            else
            {
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
                response.end(data);
            }
        });

        if(request.url == '/')
        {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end('Hello world from node.js');
        }
    }

});
server.listen(port);

function getUrlView(dat)
{
    //resolve data.
    var url = dat.lastIndexOf('?');
    url = dat.slice(0, url);

    return url;
}

function methodGet(dat)
{
    //resolve get method (requires url module).
    var url_parts = url.parse(dat, true);
    return url_parts.query;
}

function isFileView(dat)
{
    var file = dat;

    //Check if im gettint the right data.
    console.log('file is ' + dat);
    var extension = file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;

    if(extension != 0)
    {
        switch (extension)
        {
            case 'html':
                return file;
                break;

            case 'css':
                return file;
                break;

            case 'js':
                return file;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        file = file + '.html';
        return file;
    }
}
```

I'm beginner at JavaScript so with NodeJS, but I'm an experienced programmer in PHP so I don't know if the switch works in that way.

Comment: *"...the dat value returns as undefined"* Since `dat` is a function parameter, you need to follow the path backward to see where it is being called, and why it is being called with `undefined` instead of the value you expect.

Comment: `extension` seems to be an integer, but in the switch you are looking for a string..?! add a `default:` case and see if it enters there

Comment: What is the line of the error ?

Comment: the error was already shown in var extension, returning that cannot call method LastIndexOf undefined, so the server stops right there. and im sorry about newbie code, im new at this, and about the dat parameter, i dont see why it gets the error if i made it in the same way with other functions.

Comment: @nosthertus The problem is where it's called -- `isFileView(view);`. `dat`'s value will be determined by `view` and `view` isn't being given a value within the `else` block.

Comment: well. thank you for making me realize my error, but somehow this code was in a different place so i did set that parameter by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be related to how you're defining the `view` variable which you're passing as an argument to your `isFileView()` function...

```
    //if url has GET method.
    if(request.url.lastIndexOf('?') != -1)
    {
        //resolve url only view.
        var view = getUrlView(request.url);

        ....
    }
    else {
        ....
        isFileView(view); // << view isn't defined here since we never were in the 'if` statement above
        ....
    }
```

So, what you'll need to do is either define the variable before the `if` statement or inside your `else` statement or reset your function to check for an `undefined` argument so it doesn't cause any errors.

```
else {
    var view = getUrlView(request.url);
    isFileView(view); // << view isn't defined here since we never were in the 'if` statement above
    ....
}
```

Or...

```
function isFileView(dat)
{
    var file = dat || false;

    if(file) {
       ...
    }
}
```